# How to extend a Wi-Fi network with mesh devices that support EasyMesh protocol?

Tags: mesh-networking

Have a Wi-Fi router that supports EasyMesh protocol.

I would like to add satellites (not range extenders) to extend coverage, but without adding the main device as my router might be such.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It depends, In EasyMesh you certainly need a controller and in most cases the main router is the controller. You could still run EasyMesh controller on one of your satellite devices and from them into a mesh. But you will still need an uplink to your main router is it not?

Comment: The main router is 5g mobile modem (not sure about terminology) with sim card, which supports EasyMesh Wifi protocol.  The idea is to extend the network with  EasyMesh satellite units, but all as slaves. The essence of the question is - can I use the existing router as a Master for such an EasyMesh network